# regular expression for python : removing duplicate group name

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have this regular expression -

(?P<Title>.+)(?P<ReleaseYear>([0-9]+))|(?P<Title>.+)(?P<Prginfo>-[0-9])|(?P<Title>.+)(?P<Prginfo>\s+\d+\s+сезон\s*)|(?P<Title>.+)(?P<Prginfo>\s+сезон\s*\d+)|(?P<Title>.+)

This works perfectly fine in .NET code. But when I try to use it in python I am getting error  - "sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'Title' as group 3; was group 1"

Comment: Just remove the group names.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use duplicate group names in python regex because it may be cause a confusion actually python use them as a dictionary keys.

> `(?P<name>...)`
>
> Similar to regular parentheses, but the substring matched by the group is accessible via the symbolic group name name. Group names must be valid Python identifiers, **and each group name must be defined only once within a regular expression**. A symbolic group is also a numbered group, just as if the group were not named.